# Displaying custom field as well as mapped fields separately - reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

I have a mapper which takes some owners, then for each of the owners takes out some fields to populate them. I would also like to add a custom field which in my case is "Add manually" however when I put these into an array the mapped fields only appear as 1 option and I'd like them to be split up into however many there are. Here is the code I have:

```
const owningCompanyOwners = [
        company.owners.map((owner) => {
            return { label: owner.fullName + " - " + owner.role, value: owner }
        }),
        { label: "+ Add manually", value: "" }
    ]
```

Array doesn't seem like a good way of going about it in reactJS - has anyone got any other ideas? These are the options I use for my radio button.

I have also attached images of what it currently looks like and what it should look like.

**Current situation:**

[image: Current situation]

**Desired product:**

[image: Desired product]

Thank you!

Comment: Would you like to always "Add manually" exist at the end of the array?

Comment: Yes, I would @MajidMohammadi

Comment: Is `company` a state? or it's just a defined array?

Comment: A defined array - it contains mock data. I've managed to add it on by doing something along the lines of 
```owningCompanyOwners.push(
        { label: "+ Add manually", value: "" }
    )``` 
but not sure that's the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out something like this:

```
import "./styles.css";
export default function App() {
  const company = {
    owners: [
      {
        fullName: "Elsa Esvensson",
        role: "Manager"
      },
      {
        fullName: "Jonas Andersson",
        role: "Manager"
      }
    ]
  };
  const owningCompanyOwners = company.owners
    .map((owner, index) => ({
      label: owner.fullName + " - " + owner.role,
      value: owner
    }))
    .concat({ label: "+ Add manually", value: "" });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {owningCompanyOwners.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <label>{item.label}</label>
            <input name="owner" type="radio" />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit amazing-dhawan-t1wl1]